# CSS paint the table row when selected in a different color, (2 colored table)

Tags: css, colors, html-table

```
tr:first-child {background: green }
tr {background: blue  }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: red}
```

I got this, so a table with different colored rows, the even are blue and the odd are red.

Now I have the select part:

```
.selected {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

and in my table is the problem, that once I press on the red part, nothing happens, except for the change of text color...but when I press on the blue ones, all works fine...

Any suggestions?

Here is my whole html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/selected.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="appStud">

<div ng-controller="ctrlStud">

    <h2>Students</h2>
    <form>
        <p>ID</p>
        <input ng-model="student.id">
        <p>Name</p>
        <input ng-model="student.firstname">
        <p>Last Name</p>
        <input ng-model="student.lastname">

        <p>From</p>
        <select ng-model="student.mestorodjenja.ime" ng-options="x for x in names"> </select> <br> <br>


        <button ng-click="addStudent(student)">Add Student</button>
        <button ng-click="editStudent(student)">Save Student</button>
        <button ng-click="deleteStudent(student)">Delete Student</button>
        <br> <br>



    </form>
    <button ng-click="reloadRoute()">Refresh</button>
    <button ng-disabled="result.length>0" ng-click="initTables()">Init Tables</button>

    <table border=1 name="tableStud" arrow-selector>
        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td>ID</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>From</td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="student in result"
                ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}"
                ng-click="setSelected(student,$index)">
                <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.mestorodjenja.ime }}</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<br>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB/indexNaseljenoMesto.html">NaseljenaMesta</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/CreditCardWEB">Back</a>
<br>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There could be numerous reasons for that. These codes are not enough. Share your HTML of the table & JavaScript that adds the `.selected` class on click/press

Comment: Please add your HTML as well.

Comment: What happens if you add !important (e.g. background-color:black !important;) ? You'll need to post more detail than this for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: here u got the code from the html

Comment: solved! thx to zeev katz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to your `class` name exactly like you refer to your `:nth-child` selector.

---

Change `.selected` to `tr.selected` and its work fine, look at this **example**:

```css
tr:first-child {background: green }
tr {background: blue  }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: red}

tr.selected {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="selected">
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/ra6o19b1/)**

Comment: i changed it to tr.selected....and its still the same as before....the blue ones work, but the red ones dont....and i also added the class="selected" into my table....

Comment: check my example, its work. there is no reason its don't work on yours browser.

Comment: maybe you write the tr.selected selector before the :nth-child selector?

Comment: when i run ur code, from the begining, ALL the blue ones are selected, and r black, and the text is white, but the red ones r still red, but the text is white....

Comment: bro, u solved it, its not before, but afther the tr:nth-child selector

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your trying to do here exactly.But I assume its either,

1) trying to change the background colour when the user hovers over a row.

2) Or when the user clicks on a row the .selected class is applied.

If your going for 1 then you can use the css pseudo :hover

If number 2 then you will need to use javascript to change the class when the user clicks.

Comment: the 2nd part is for me relevant...can u explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the .select part should go after the tr:nth-child part

then all works just like is should!!